# Exception when uses WriteObject

Tags: c#, json, datacontractserializer

I am trying to add some parameters to a Json stream. But when I try to WriteObject an excpetion aquired. What am I doing wrong?

```
Stream responseStream = e.Result;

Params par = new Params();
par.id = "1";
par.jsonrpc = "2.0";
par.method = "getPosts";
par.param = new Param { page = "0"};

DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Params));
ser.WriteObject(responseStream, par);
Params response = (Params)ser.ReadObject(responseStream);
```

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). On SO a lot of people spend a lot of their time to help others. So please show some effort to reduce theirs. Maybe a little bit more information about the exception would be nice.

Comment: what is e and e.Result?  Are you sure that is a stream you can write to?